# Exclude cache on public folder for blogdown

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

When I build my site using blogdown, the cached files from Rmd posts are copied across to the public directory. This is unnecessary, wastes space, and slows down the deployment.

I think I can use `blogdown::build_site()` with the `custom` argument to avoid this, if I provide my own `custom` script. What should the custom script look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The build method is irrelevant, because it only defines the behavior of **blogdown** instead of Hugo. It is Hugo that copied your files to `public/`. I have not documented it yet, but typically you want Hugo to ignore these files (like [what I did in the default example](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium-theme/blob/d8b33cf197795f11f039f174a5524897fc563f01/exampleSite/config.toml#L8)):

```
ignoreFiles = ["\\.Rmd$", "_files$", "_cache$"]
```

This option is to be set in the config file (e.g. `config.toml`).

Comment: Thanks. I should have started with your default example!

Comment: That is definitely not your problem. I'm still trying hard to catch up the documentation.